# Why do facebook like buttons not work when there are multiple on the page?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, api

I am trying to create a facebook like website here http://likes.vermilionsite.com/ but when you like a post they like for a fraction of a second and unlike again, could someone explain how to fix this, is it because there is interference with the multiple buttons?

This is my source code:

```
$sql_all = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 0,20")or die(mysql_error());
while($row_all = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_all)){
$x++;
    echo "<div id=\"item".$x."\" class=\"item\">";
    echo $row_all['content']."<br><br>";
    echo "<div id=\"fb-root\"></div><script src=\"http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=251780764837127&amp;xfbml=1\"></script><fb:like href=\"http://likes.vermilionsite.com/message.php?id=".$row_all['id']."\" send=\"false\" width=\"450\" show_faces=\"false\" font=\"\"></fb:like>";
    echo "<hr>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id=\"fb-root\"></div>
<script src=\"http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=251780764837127&amp;xfbml=1\"></script>
```

this should only be once in your code, that could be the issue.

Comment: No I didn't know there was one.

Comment: Yes, there is a PHP SDK, I'd try working with that and getting 1 like button to work successfully, before trying to do what you are attempting....

Comment: but it has nothing to do with php really does it? I don't want to create anything dynamic other than the id.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial on how to get multiple like buttons that link different things at : http://www.seriousreport.com/metatags_howtogetmultiplelikebuttons.php